# Change the style of Listview item button at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I want to change the style of an Accessory button in ListView Item. I'm using a Custom style (Jet style) that is shipped with RAD Studio.

The Accessory Button has 2 style objects. The style names as follows :  one is normal(`accessorymore`), and the other is when the item is selected(`accessorymoreselected`). Now, the style changes if the Listview item is selected. However, I disabled the selection in the Listview. I want to change the style of when I press the Accessory button itself.

I've Added a custom png image named `Selected.png` for the `accessorymoreselected` style by utilizing the Bitmap designer using the source link property of the StyleObject.

On the `ListViewItemClickEx` Event :

```
 TListView(ListView1.Items[ItemIndex].View.FindObject('Acc')).StyleLookup := 'Selected.png';
```

I get an Access violation. How to properly change the style of the accessory button if clicked ?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that 'ListView1.Items[ItemIndex].View.FindObject('Acc')' returns a TListView obect. And since this is a unchecked cast, this would explan the AV. You can find out by using '(ListView1.Items[ItemIndex].View.FindObject('Acc') as TListView' which will raisn an EInvalidCast exception if it is the wrong type.

Comment: Reveiwe queue: Comment already entered

Comment: I see. I don't have much knowledge with typecasting. that's why I ask here :) @H.Hasenack . Thanks